# Long Shadow with gradient depending on length

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows

I am trying to use Cycles to create a shadow effect that will decrease intensity based on the length of the shadow. 
But I am only able to achieve this : [image]

What I am doing is I am calculating transparency based on the distance to the point that's rendered. (might be dumb)

[image]

I don't want the shadows to overlap. 
I wouldn't mind to change the way I do it if there's a better solution.

Scene I am using : 
[image]

Edit. 
This is what happens when I multiply the factor that used as factor to mix the shaders with the Ray Length : 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23934/3710

Comment: This isn't exactly related as I want a hard shadow that decreases it's intensity in relation to distance. But the main difference is that mine is a hard shadow ( Size of Light set to 0 ) and theirs isn't.

Comment: This seems interesting, though I'm not sure of understand correctly what you would like to achieve. Could you show a 3D view of your scene and a mock-up of the expected result?

Comment: I've edited the original post and added overview and side view images. The directional light is slightly angled to cast a shadow ( wouldn't do so otherwise since the Size is set to zero )

Comment: Have you tried using the Ray Length output?

Comment: I posted another image showing what happens when I multiply it with the factor I am using to mix the two shaders

Comment: Just for the purposes of creating an example, what does the material for the background plane look like?

Comment: It's just a Diffuse BSDF with Color White and Roughness 0 which is attached to the surface vlaue of the material output